# Как перезагрузить js после обновления страницы ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Написал код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.left-menu ul li').toggle(function () {
        $('.left-menu ul li ul').animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 150);
        $(this).find('ul:first').animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 150);
    });
});
```

Но после обновления ajax, скрипт перестает работать.

Здесь происходит обновление:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <div class="left-menu">
                <h:form styleClass="genres" id="genresForm">
                    <ul>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{genreController.genreGroups}" var="c">
                            <li class="qwert">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>#{c.name}</b>
                                <ul class="border">
                                    <ui:repeat value="#{genreController.getGenresByGroup(c.id)}" var="g">
                                        <li>
                                            <p:commandLink update=":booksForm:booksList @form :lettersForm  :booksCount" value="#{g.name}" styleClass="#{g.id == bookListController.selectedGenreId ? 'selected_link':''}" actionListener="#{bookListController.fillBooksByGenre()}">
                                                <f:param name="genre_id" value="#{g.id}" />
                                            </p:commandLink>
                                        </li>
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </ul>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Приведите код для начала в читаемое состояние и... покажите, что у Вас там за обновление ajax.

Comment: то есть после нажатия по .left-menu ul li ul li , идет выборка книг, но после этого не могу раскрыть .left-menu ul li

Comment: `.toggle()` в таком варианте, кстати, был deprecated в версии 1.8, а в версии 1.9 был удалён. Использовать его вообще не стоит. Я с `<h:body>` и т.д. не знаком, но если проблема в том, что элементы из  `.left-menu ul li` чем-то изменяются (некоторые элементы удаляются, некоторые добавляются), и из-за этого код внутри функций у `.toggle()` не отрабатывает на новых элементах, то это исправить можно.

Answer (score 1):

Обновить всю страницу со вложенными ресурсами

```
<p:commandLink update="@all" />
```